# Can I use django orm with a database that was not set up with django

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have a database that I set up manually using raw sql and alembic. I want to now use this database in a Django app. Will the Django ORM work as expected with this DB? Would I have to set up all the models? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- `manage.py inspectdb` will create models for you from an existing database, see [inspectdb docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb)
- models created via `inspectdb` have attribute `managed = False` in their `Meta` class, which will tell Django to not perform any modifications upon such models, see docs for [managed attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/options/#managed)